# Cordova local plugin (Visual Studio 2015) issue

Tags: cordova, plugins, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community, and I have this issue with cordova plugin.
I've made a custom local plugin on my machine, and I am trying to add it to my cordova project from config.xml:

View-Designer-> Plugins-> Custom -> Local -> ...

As I set the path to local plugin, I am getting this error:

```
Visual Studio unable to parse plugin.xml. Please ensure plugin.xml exists and contains no errors.
```

I've uploaded the plugin to Git and then added as custom plugin, and it worked!!

Any ideas how to solve this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but as I changed the folder which contains the plugin everything worked.

Both folders was set as readonly